# Bluetooth: Uart or SPI?

Tags: bluetooth, hardware, uart, spi

My question is : what is the best method to drive a bluetooth module(BTM-331 as an example) over UART or SPI? I am asking this in the following context. 
I have some analog sensors connected to a uP. The uP sends this data over spi to another uP who has also a bluetooth module. Because I talk with the sensors via SPI is ok to talk with the Bluetooth module with spi or uart is better?

Comment: You're comparing a device to an interface. By "UART" do you mean RS232? RS232 is more robust in terms of hot-plugging.  SPI is intended for on-board (hard wired) peripherals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that even if you want to use it with SPI, you can't. I've used other BTM modules and the SPI on them is used for programming the module. Communication with it is possible through UART and (most of the times) USB. 
Looking at the BTM 331 ([description here](http://www.rayson.com/rayson/en/index.php?pros=solutions&solution_type=SOL07&item=view&prod_id=P0011)) and it does say that USB and UART are the interfaces used.

Other than that it is fairly simple to use, you send data to it and the data goes to whoever the module is connected to. That is the least you can do with it but it is more than enough for most people.